# how to connect to standalone selenium-firefox container from another container

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, dockerfile

I am trying to run my automation GUI test suites which is located in my automation container.

I seperately downloaded standalone selenium-firefox image and running as container running on port 4444. which is running on

```
localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

Now, I am trying to run the test suites which is in my automation container, i am using below code to run in headless mode to reach the firefox version of selenium in my robotframework test suite.

```
Open Browser      http://www.youtube.com    headlessfirefox    remote_url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

This approach is working fine when i run my test suite from my machine, it fails when i run it inside the automation container.

is there any way that my automation container can reach the selenium-firefox container to use the browser.

Error:

```
C: 10: Open Chrome headless                                          
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: 
RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.3) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't 
match a supported version!
RequestsDependencyWarning)
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7f4a322440b8>: Failed to establish a
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7f4a32244710>: Failed to establish a
new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /wd/hub/session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7f4a32235710>: Failed to establish a
new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /wd/hub/session
| FAIL |
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4444): Max 
retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7f4a32235438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] 
Connection refused',))
```

Any help would be thankful

Comment: Instead of localhost run it by using your maching IP

Comment: have you tried like that: 'http://chrome:4444/wd/hub' ?or firefox you do

Comment: The issue here comes from docker networking. On the default network, no aliases are given, as explained below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container is considered a different machine, network-wise. When you launch the selenium-firefox image, you probably link the port 4444 of your container with port 4444 of your host. Then, when you request localhost:4444 on your host, it links to your container.

But when you launch another container, localhost:4444 means port 4444 of this container !

What you should do is use the embed dns mechanic docker offers : when you create a container, it has a name (thar you can specify). Docker gives it an internal ip on the default docker network **but does not** associate the container name with that ip. To be able to use the container name as a domain name in your urls, you need to create a new network, which then will user the embed docker dns and get it's own name as an alias.

That is why Vova answer was working : docker-compose creates a network by default for your container, which means they get an alias automatically. I was so used to use network and/or compose that I overlooked the fact that alias weren't automatic on the default docker network.

You shoudl create a specific bridge network only for those containers : `docker network create selenium-net --driver bridge`

Then `docker run -p 4444:4444 --name selenium --network selenium-net selenium/standalone-firefox:latest`

When you run your other container, you should also add them in the `selenium-net` network

An alternative is to connect the containers you already have to the network : let's say I have containers `selenium` and `testsuite` running (or existing)
I will run `docker network connect selenium-net selenium` and `docker network connect selenium-net testsuite` to put them in the network. When you do that, you can specify the `--alias` option if you want to give them a particuliar alias/domain on the docker network.

Comment: i tried your way i have ran the firefox as you suggested , and used the below line 
Open Browser      http://www.youtube.com    firefox   
 remote_url=http://selenium:4444/wd/hub
but no use.. still getting the same error

Comment: how could we start a container without using port option?

Comment: You just don't write it. You don't have to link ports when you start a container.

Comment: did ran, still same error
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS
        NAMES
857e14e62e15   selenium/standalone-firefox:latest   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   28 minutes ago   Up 28 minutes               4444/tcp
        selenium
ba8f5b8e95e3   mytest_env                      "python3"                10 hours ago     Up 10 hours                 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   testautomation

still same error

Comment: Found the solution ! I put it in my answer. Tests are working on my containers, using selenium python library directly. Robot Framework should work also.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me . Thanks a lot . I was searching for solution from past one week. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create docker-compose.yml file with all of the containers what you're going to create:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:85.0
    hostname: chrome
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  e2e-tests:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - chrome
```

and use host name 'chrome' inside container what is going to use it like:

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://chrome:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```